# Problem with Initialization cell and Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, initialization

The following minimum failing example illustrates a problem that I am having building an application to simulate projectile motion.

In the notebook's initialization cell, I have the definition of a function `FlightDuration`. It serves as a stand-in for a library function that computes the duration of the projectile's flight from its initial conditions.

```
(* Initialization cell *)
FlightDuration[(* arguments *)] := 16.3;
```

The main input cell of the notebook contains a `Manipulate` for setting the values of the initial conditions and a Trigger for running the simulation.

```
(* Normal (Input) cell: *)
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol=DSolve[{y''[t]==-9.8,y'[0]==80,y[0]==0},y,t]},
  flightDuration=FlightDuration[(* control values *)];
  Plot[
   y[t]/.sol,
   {t,0.0001,time},
   PlotRange->{{0,flightDuration},{-50,400}},
   ImageSize->500
  ]
 ],
 (* other controls supplying values to FlightDuration *)
 {{time,0.},0.,flightDuration,ControlType->Trigger},
 {{flightDuration,FlightDuration[]},None}
]
```

When I close the normal cell, save the notebook, quit Mathematica and restart Mathematica by double clicking the notebook, the Output cell shows a red border and I see the error message:

> General: Value of option PlotRange -> {{0,FlightDuration[]},{-50,400}}
> is not All, Full, Automatic,  a positive machine number, or an
> appropriate list of range specifications.

However, if I then click the Play button, the simulation works as expected.

My initial (naive) expectation was that the evaluation of the initialization cell should complete before any displays are updated. Further reflection suggested that perhaps the front end was trying to update the display at the same time that the kernel was evaluating the initialization cell. I tried various ways of delaying the re-display, such as using a semaphore, without success.

Q1: Does Mathematica provide an programmatic way for me to control when the initial display update takes place?

Q2: What is the best practice for initializing a notebook along the lines I am trying to do?

Note: Occasionally, when opening the notebook, the error does not occur. I take this to mean that there is some kind of timing dependency or race condition.

Environment: Mathematica: 12.1.0.0; MacBook Pro; Mac OS-X 10.13.4

Comment: Check SaveDefinitions, or trigger initialization cells from Initialization with front end tokens. I would need to do some testing but afaict Initialization cells are not pulled by existing dynamics.

Comment: @Kuba: Can you elaborate a little?
- Doesn't SaveDefinitions automatically apply to DynamicModules?
- What do you mean by "pulled"?

Comment: They are both false by default: `Options[#, SaveDefinitions] & /@ {Manipulate, DynamicModule}`. By pulled I mean when this option is True then rules/definitions associated with relevant symbols are included in DynamicModule/Manipulate and if the kernel dies/you open UI in a new session then everything is in place.